# How do I embed JavaScript into SSRS reports?

Tags: javascript, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I've tried to create an expression for an action button in my report using JavaScript as follows:

```
="javascript:void(window.open(‘http://dwh/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx?ItemPath=%2fReports%2fANEXIA%2fANEXIA+-+new’, ‘Odvod tržeb řidiči‘))"
```

...unfortunately which returns an error when run:

```
The URL javascript:void(window.open(‘http://dwh/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx?ItemPath=%2fReports%2fANEXIA%2fANEXIA+-+new’, ‘Odvod tržeb řidiči‘)) has an invalid schema. URLs in reports may only use http://, https://, ftp://, file:, mailto: or news: (rsUnsupportedURLProtocol)
```

How can I run JavaScript in my reports?

Comment: So you want to click on a button in the report and go to another page? Make a textbox. Style it to look like a button, then right click it go properties and select Action.

Comment: Yes, but I'd like to open a new window.

Comment: Then it's probably best to do the JS on the actual web page. SSRS can't do that.

Comment: Actually, I've found out that it works when a placeholders properties / Mark Type is set to HTML.